# NSMutable String: How do I get the index of multiple spaces in a string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, string

I want to find the index of the 8th occurrence of "  " so that I could split my string there. However all I can find is this line of code that gives me an array of all the occurrences of "  ". Is there a function I can call that would give me this information?

```
 int numberOfOccurences = [[myListString componentsSeparatedByString:@"  "] count];
```

Edit 1: So far this is the solution I came up with:

```
 if(numberOfOccurences > 8)
{
    //find index of place where you want to split by picking an
    //arbitrary number and finding the first white space
    int index = (int)[[myListString substringFromIndex:45] rangeOfString:@"  "].location;

    NSLog(@"Index: %i", index);

    //make substring
    NSString *substringList1 = [myListString substringToIndex:(45+index)];
    NSString *substringList2 = [myListString substringFromIndex:(45+index)];
 }
```

Comment: You'll need to do it iteratively, finding each successive space in the string until you reach 8.

Comment: Your solution both makes no sense, and looks like a terrible way to do things.

Comment: @stonz2 My Solution gives me the result I was looking for. Why do you think it is so bad?

Comment: Your "solution" only works when there is exactly 7 spaces in the first 45 characters.

Answer (score 1):

There is no method to find the *8th* space, but there are the building blocks you need.

The `NSString` method `rangeOfString:options:range:` will find the first occurrence of its first argument within the range specified by its third argument, it returns a range for the match. You simply start with the third argument being the whole string and then iterate reducing the range to search using the previous result.

If you are actually looking for white space and not simply a space you might consider the similar `rangeOfCharactersFromSet` methods.

If you don't really want the eighth space, but are trying to break a string at a given length, you can look at `componentsSeparatedByString`/`componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet` and then reassemble the resultant “words" into strings of the appropriate length. You might also want to look at `NSScanner`.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I came up with my own hacky way of doing it that I added to my original post. Too bad there isn't a quick one liner built in.

Answer (score 1):

With the explicit assumption that you are looking for the eighth space (*and possibly needing to adjust the regex a little depending on character set*), you could use a regular expression:

```
NSRegularExpression *exp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^([^ ]* ){8}+"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                        error:NULL];

NSRange result = [exp rangeOfFirstMatchInString:input options:0 range:inputRange];
```

If `result.location != NSNotFound` then `result.length` gives you the index on which to split.